# Is passing value types by ref more performant for large iterations?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

For example:

```
void Foo(ref int x, ref string s, ref MyStruct ms)
{ // Do stuff with them }
```

Consider this function to be called a large number of times such as 50000+ times. There's memory accessing, allocation, and garbage collection happening, and I don't know if or at which point you would see a performance gain, in terms of speed, by passing by ref in this type of example.

Comment: There's no point in debating unless you profile the code, even more if it gets compiled to IL2CPP.

Comment: Rule of thumb has always been 16 bytes is worthwhile to `ref` (note that `string` is itself pointer-sized in this context), but it really depends on the code (which you need to properly profile) as inlining, dynamic slicing and eliding can make a huge difference here. It's highly likely there are better things to worry about anyway. 50,000 times is really not much in the grand scheme of things. If you were talking billions, maybe....

Answer (score 1):

Passing by ref can really help if you are passing structs. It's easy to forget that structs are value types, so when you call a function with a struct, the function operates on a copy of the struct. Depending on the size of the struct and the number of calls this could be a huge performance impact. I recently worked on some image processing code that did a lot of work with the Point struct. By passing the struct by ref I got a huge performance increase.

Also depending on the version of the language you're using, you can also pass parameters using `in` which means to pass a reference, but don't let the function change it.